# Why/how do people have Ringed City weapons as early as Farron Keep?

Tags: dark-souls-3

I'm level 23, with a +1 Bastard Sword. Part of the Watch Dogs. I do pretty alright in PVP. But I do run into people with like the ringed knight set, the split leaf greatsword, and even a couple paired ringed knight greatswords. My settings shouldn't allow this so I'm very confused. Also invaded people who were using soul spear,dark edge, and homing soulmass.

I'm old to Dark Souls but new to the PVP so I'm confused how I could be facing this. I really don't see what the fun of that is.

Answer (score 5):

As there are no level limits for game progression, it is possible to get to DLC on any level. And while knowing weapon requirements, it is possible to level up according to requirements. E.g., while starting as Deprived, it is possible to meet requirements on level 23.

Therefore, it is possible to get DLC weapon on 23-25 lvl and roll in PVP with it.

Comment: Additionally you can simply get someone to drop you the weapons, armors, rings, etc. You can't drop spells however.

Answer (score 0):

People use twinks, new characters handed end game gear to dominate normal players.